# Passing a wstring pointer to a 3rd party SO written in c++

Tags: python, c++, c, linux, python-3.x

I am writing a simple python 3.5 wrapper for a .SO that was coded in c++. Facing a function that expects a **comtypes.BSTR*** pointer I've hit a block, since I'm working on linux (ubuntu 16.04) (not changeable) and cannot use python's *comtypes* lib which is windows-only. I have an example containing some C++ code that calls the .SO , and there they are using **wstring** as a replacement for BSTR:

```
#define BSTR        wstring
```

my problem is that *ctypes* does not support wstring as a possible type, as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53136004/2684237) answer. 
So how do I get python to pass a pointer to a **wstring**? Is there no way short of wrapping the SO in another SO, written in C and more suited to usage with python? Note I cannot change anything in the .SO I'm using so the solution here ideally is python-based...

Comment: Have you tried cython or pybind11 for this task?

Comment: The easiest and most productive way to create a Python wrapper for C++ code is with libraries like pybind11 or boost.python. Both support wide strings out of the box.

Comment: If you want a purely Python-based solution, you can try ctypes which also supports wchar_t based strings. It can only handle C-compatible types and interfaces though. However the utility of wchar_t is rather dubious. We handle almost evetything with UTF-8 these days, and that's the way we likes it.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - thanks, I have looked into both, but as I'm not proficient in C or C++ I really hoped there would be a way to achieve this in python3. guess not.

Comment: @n.m.          If I'm not mistaken ctypes cannot be used to call a function that expects *wstring or other c++ types. out of pybind11 and boost.python, which do you find easier?

Comment: Right, it only works with C types, which is why it is called ctypes. You would need to convert between C-style strings and C++-style strings at the .so side. I find pybind11 much easier because it is a header-only library.

Comment: I opted on wrapping the 3rd part lib with my own very simple CPP code that converts whatever is necessary within methods defined as "extern c". so everything is accessible using ctypes types. Not sure if that counts as an answer though... does it?